# IIS ReWrite Rule to remove query string when contains specific specific query string

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

Looking to remove a particular query string parameter. Folder name can be different and length of the `specs` param can vary with any combination of numbers. Whenever there is a `specs` parameter, regardless of the value, strip that parameter and redirect to `http://example.com/folder`

Example Inputs:

- `http://example.com/folder1?specs=10,13,14,18,20,29`
- `http://example.com/folder2?specs=14,18,20`

Would redirect to (respectively):

- `http://example.com/folder1`
- `http://example.com/folder2`

Do not strip any other query string params. i.e.
`http://example.com/folder1?page=1` would not get redirected.

Rule Tried, not working, despite seeming like it would when using the IIS rewrite rules test tools:

```
<rule name="SpecsSpiderCrawl" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(\/\/.*\/)(.*)\?" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="specs=.*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was making it too hard. This worked:

```
<rule name="SpecsSpiderCrawl" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="specs=.*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

- `{HTTP_HOST}` is just the example.com portion of the uri
- `{R:0}` will get the folder name
- `appendQueryString="false"` will remove the entire query string (which is fine for my use case.